# Panels Accordian - "this pane needs a title" Message

Tags: panels

Hello i have an install of Panoply on [MY WEBSITE](http://onlinebanter.com/). I cant work out if Panels Accordian Style came with panoply or if its default. Ive stripped Panolpy right down and still dont see anything that could be cauing my Panels Accord Style barr it coming with panles so anyhow.

When i use the style i get an 'This pane needs a title!' message on all my block headers. Can anyone work out why this maybe so?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried giving it a title?

Comment: Thanks for the reply beth. Ive gave them all titles 6 times over beth. ive put title where titles dont even....lol. Ive got a feelign its somethign to do with the accordian style pluging not picking up the h2 (or h3 - i havent looked) block title. I had that problem before with D6 accordian modules. Keep them ideas a coming folks